# MySQL ranking based on score and time played

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables as follows

**Table: *score***

[image]

**Table: *user***

[image]

My requirement is to rank the score and retrieve if the score total_score is greater than some value (for example rank all score if total_score is less than 15). If scores are equal then consider time too.

I wrote the following query to fetch the rows including rank (I'm not much familiar with SQL queries but I tried to findout a way to do this - no luck).

**Attempt - 1**

```
SELECT score.total_score,
       CONCAT(users.user_first_name,' ', users.user_last_name) AS name,
       users.user_email,
       FIND_IN_SET(total_score,
                     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(total_score
                                          ORDER BY total_score ASC)
                      FROM score)) AS rank
FROM score
INNER JOIN users ON score.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE score.total_score > 15
ORDER BY score.total_score DESC LIMIT 10
```

**Attempt - 2**

```
SET @Rank := 0;
SELECT score.total_score,score.time,
       CONCAT(users.user_first_name,' ', users.user_last_name) AS name,
       users.user_email,
       @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS rank
FROM score
INNER JOIN users ON score.score_id = users.user_id
WHERE score.total_score > 15
ORDER BY score.total_score DESC, time ASC LIMIT 10
```

Both attempts are failed, in short what I tried to do is,

Rank user scores according to total_score by considering time (there is chances to have same scores).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whay are you joining on "score_id" and "user_id" ? Shouldn't it be "ON score.user_id = users.user_id" ?

Comment: 1. See normalisation. 2. Normalise your schema.

Comment: Id highly recommendremoving the columns for level 2 to 4. And adding a new column "level". Just set the level there and the score. That way it doesn't matter if you have 2 levels, or 900 levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. `ORDER BY (score.total_score/score.time)`

```
SET @Rank := 0;
SELECT score.total_score, score.time,
       CONCAT(users.user_first_name,' ', users.user_last_name) AS name,
       users.user_email,
       (@Rank := @Rank + 1) AS rank
FROM score
INNER JOIN users ON score.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE score.total_score > 15
ORDER BY (score.total_score/score.time) ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? It's sorted. or do you mean you want the field `rank` will be fixed too?

Comment: The rank field is not fixed.

Comment: @Nikhil I updated it. You can try it again. It should do the job.

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94902/1/1 the rank is not showing properly. The main purpose it to get the rank of the user.

Thanks.

Comment: In my first case the ranking is working but if there is tie then the ranking is not working. So I need to consider time in that case (if less time then the user will be first).